# pig processing how to make multiple maps into single map and put in to bag?

Tags: apache-pig

Actual output:

```
{((["plan_type":"RATEPLAN_TYPE"],
   ["plan_code":"RATEPLAN_CODE"],
   ["market_code":"RATEPLAN_MARKETCODE"]))}
```

expected output:

```
[{"plan_type":"rateplantype",
  "plan_code":"ratecode",
  "market_code":"mrktcode"`}]
```

how to get the above output?